# How to get Network Speed in WebRTC

Tags: javascript, web, webrtc

I have implemented WebRTC for a JavaScript video conferencing application. I need to calculate the internet speed during video/audio calls and depending on it show a message grading the connection as 
Poor/Average/Good/Excellent. Please suggest the best possible way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/audio/
shows how to use the getStats API to calculate the difference between the number of bits sent. Another thing you might consider is the round trip time which is available from the same API.

Comment: How did you accomplished it ?